# Creating a Background Process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm wondering, how can we create a background process which notifies users (even after terminating the app)?

I've tried creating a window with `skipTaskbar:true`, but it can't be initiated without user's gesture.

Comment: What do you mean by "when they are not using our app"? A background service? is the app opened or stopped?

Comment: @briosheje I mean when user stopped the app.

Comment: There is currently no way, as far as I know, to have a background service like a .NET or whatever one with electron. Electron is just the framework that holds a web application in a windows/unix/macosx process. You can use other technologies (I would suggest you using nodejs or similar) to run an "endless" or "forever" background-process that interacts with electron, but there is no such an evident feature provided by electron. The closest you can get is create another electron application that have NO GUI and talks with your electron application through other channels.

Comment: To make things clearer: I would try to create a parallel electron application (that you may call "your application service") that has NO GUI but interacts with the OS and **has a tray icon**, using such, you can run your background tasks and notify the user when something happens. If something happens, either provide a GUI or just execute something that runs the main application. You may also choose another valid alternative: detect the "close" button and prevent the application shutdown by keeping it opened as a tray icon (and load the GUI onclick, while running background tasks).

Comment: @briosheje can you post your comment as an answer so that I can give a green tick to it, because I understood what you'v said.

Comment: Try to solve the problem first and come back here by editing the question if you have any issue related to it, my comments are so vague that I personally don't consider them as answers, but rather as tips. I would suggest you the second way though: there is an event called "window-all-closed" in the main.js file that detects whether the app is going to be closed: you might want to detect the event and prevent it's default behavior. Alternatively, you can spawn an hidden window and such event will never be called (though I don't recommend it). Just try it and tell if it works ;).

Answer (score 0):

One library called Background.js to handle a few scenarios: a sequential background queue (based on the WorkerQueue library), a list of jobs where each is called on every timer, and an array iterator to help break up your work into smaller chunks. Examples and code here:

https://github.com/kmalakoff/background

Or

You can also use below code for background task.

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Count numbers: <output id="result"></output></p>
<button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button> 
<button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not support Web Workers.</p>

<script>
var w;

function startWorker() {
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
            w = new Worker("demo_workers.js");
        }
        w.onmessage = function(event) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
        };
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers...";
    }
}

function stopWorker() { 
    w.terminate();
    w = undefined;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `Worker` works even after terminating electron app?